# Should I update multiple VBO's with multiple glBufferSubData() calls or a single VBO with one glBufferSubData() call?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I have 38 particle systems with different shaders, and each particle system can be rendered up to 200 times at different places(emitters) in the world.
The only thing I need to update(upload to GPU) each frame is emitter positions(and maybe some other attributes in some systems), 
if and only if any particle system is active and visible in the viewing frustum.

**Should I allocate and update everything like this:**
-Allocate a single VBO for each particle system that can handle up to 200 emitters. Update 0 to 200 emitters each frame for each particle system with glBufferSubData().
Perform a single draw call for each particle system.

We need to perform 38 glBufferSubData() calls in the worst case scenario with this method!

**OR, should I do it like this(Shared VBO):**
-Allocate a very large VBO that can handle up to 38(particle systems) * 200(emitters per particle system). Update all the particle systems with a single
call to glBufferSubData(). In this case, we need to group all the emitters for each particle system, 
because each draw call must know the start offset for each particle system and its emitters.
Perform a single draw call for each particle system.

We need to call glBufferSubData() only one time!

It sounds obvious that case nr 2 is the winner, but I have some doubts. We know that 38 particle systems is sharing a single VBO, 
but what about stalling the GPU pipeline? 
The graphics driver can only perform a VBO update if and only if all the 38 particle systems is finished with rendering, i.e. not reading any data from the VBO.

I found this: **Consider using multiple buffer objects to avoid stalling the rendering pipeline during data store updates. If any rendering in the pipeline makes reference to data in the buffer object being updated by glBufferSubData, especially from the specific region being updated, that rendering must drain from the pipeline before the data store can be updated.**

Here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml

Should I use double or even triple buffering for case nr 2?

Comment: 38*200 = 7600 positions is nothing. The GPU should render them in a short blinking. Why bother?

Comment: Each emitter position represents 150-300 particles on the GPU. The big question is, how the CPU-GPU transfer should be handled and not the GPU computation/rendering part.

Comment: OK. 2 million is not so small, but still not so big. Benchmark it. In the case both ways are slow (for the first way, draw the half, upload and draw the rest) You better read the chapter 28 Asynchronous... at http://openglinsights.com/

Comment: Thanks Ripi2, a very nice article! 
My solution: Allocate triple buffering with Round Robin and do a single call to glBufferSubData() each frame(if any particle system is visible in our frustum). 
glMapBufferRange() can be faster than glBufferSubData(), but multi-threaded drivers can FORCE sync even if we specify GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT according to AZDO(Approaching zero driver overhead). Persistent mapped streaming requires OpenGL 4.4...

Answer (score 3):

Like a lot of optimizations when it comes to graphics, it's a trade-off. By consolidating all the buffers into one, you're reducing the number of state changes necessary to draw your particle systems for the average case. But you are then missing out on reduced bus bandwidth if you skip a `glBufferSubData()` when a system is not in the frustum.

I wouldn't be concerned with stalling the GPU pipeline unless the whole buffer were more than a few MB large (think size of a frame or two in a high-res video stream). Changing a VBO is a much cheaper state change than changing a shader or framebuffer.

It mostly comes down to what you have more of to spare: GPU processing/syncrhonization time (in the form of state changes) or PCI-e bus bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, it can be hard sometimes to choose between different solutions. 
My solution: Allocate three large buffer objects with Round Robin(Avoid implicit synchronization) and allocate a large vector of floats.
This vector contains all the information that can be seen in our frustum this frame, and this vector will be uploaded to the GPU by doing a single call to glBufferSubData().